# Getting forbidden error for AWS Lambda Function URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, url, aws-lambda

I have created a basic lambda with lambda function url.

```
auth_type = aws_iam
```

allowed permissions for ec2 role in lambda resource based policy.

created a role to ec2 instance with full lambda permissions in the policy and attached it to the ec2 instance.

While invoking it from ec2 as below its getting forbidden error.

```
curl "https://<url-id>.lambda-url.<region>.on.aws"
```

I have tried with auth_type as none. Its working, but not working when i try with auth_type as aws_iam.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html), to invoke a lambda url with `AWS_IAM`, you have to **sign** your url request by constracting special URL which has your signature. Please check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) on how to construct a valid signature for URL requests.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add more details to the previous answer, you can invoke Lambda URL using the  following command:

```
curl --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:<REGION>:lambda" \
      --user "<ACCESS-KEY-ID>:<SECRET-KEY-ID>" \
      'https://<URL-ID>.lambda-url.<REGION>.on.aws/?message=HelloWorld' \
      -H 'content-type: application/json' \
      -d '{ "key": "value" }'
```

I added frequently used parameters to the request in case you need to pass them as well.